# Implementing Firebase Dynamic Link service on the web

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Can anyone share their experience with implementing Firebase Dynamic Link service on the web? I need some assistance with making it work on localhost and passing query parameters to my Angular web app. Thank you!

I have tried to pass custom parameters but they are being removed and redirected to the web app without those parameters

for generating I used this

```
    createDynamicLink(args: CreateDynamicLinkArgs): Observable<string> {
    const {link, queryParams, title, description} = args;

    const uri = new URL(`${this.config.baseUrl}/${link}`);
    uri.search = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();

    const dynamicLinkParams: {dynamicLinkInfo: DynamicLinkInfo} = {
        dynamicLinkInfo: {
            domainUriPrefix: `${uri.protocol}//${uri.host}`,
            link: uri.toString(),
            androidInfo: this.config.androidParameters,
            iosInfo: this.config.iosParameters,
            socialMetaTagInfo: {
                socialTitle: title,
                socialDescription: description,
                socialImageLink: this.config.socialImageLink
            }
        }
    };

    const url = `${this.config.firebase.baseUrl}/${this.config.firebase.shortLinkPath}?key=${this.config.firebase.apiKey}`;

    return this.httpService.post<{shortLink: string}>(url, dynamicLinkParams).pipe(
        map(({data}) => data.shortLink),
        catchError(err => {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(err?.message);
        })
    );
}
```

After successfully generating the link, I receive a link like https://links.domain.com/Ha2fJ7W1o7Usu64P6. When this link is clicked, it redirects to https://links.domain.com/clip?clipId=409685. Finally, it redirects to http://localhost:4200/clips without the clip ID.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.